# Python. Лямбда в словаре. Не работает print()

Tags: python, lambda

Есть такой словарь:

```
l = {
"1":lambda x=input("x= "),y=input("y= "):print(x,y)
}

l["1"]
```

При вызове не выводит **x** и **y**. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

в l["1"] у вас лежит функция. Чтобы она что то напечатала, ее нужно выполнить:

```
l["1"]()
```

Comment: скобки не починят тот факт, что [`input()` сразу вызывается.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/466241/23044)

Answer (score 3):

Код сломан. `l["1"]()` не достаточно, чтобы его починить: `input()` вызывается во время создания словаря.

Нужно переместить вызовы внутрь функции и если хочется по индексам обращаться, то можно список вместо словаря использовать:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
functions = [lambda: print(input('x= '), input('y= '))]
print('до вызова')
functions[0]() 
print('после вызова')
```

Comment: А в Python определен порядок вычисления аргументов?

Comment: Точно, что значения по умолчанию для аргументов вычисляются в момент *определения* функции, а не её вызова. Порядок в `lambda x=input("x= "),y=input("y= "): None` слева-направо, но точно не помню -- никогда, такой код не писал (чтобы результат зависел от порядка вычисления аргументов).